# How to delete data in dbo.Customer etc from Northwind?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am trying to delete existence data from Northwind database either from the Dynamic Data Site nor manually from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. However none of it seems working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What have you tried? What didn't work? Did you get an error message? What was it?

Answer (score 0):

The Customer data is heavily related to lots of other tables, such as Orders, Invoices and stuff like that.

You'll have to delete all the data that relies on the customer data first.